# How does Oracle's TO_NUMBER() determine the return NUMBER datatype?

Tags: oracle, types, numbers, integer

I am currently doing some research on Oracle functions, and one thing that stumped me a bit is how Oracle determines the return datatype of TO_NUMBER().

TO_NUMBER() takes in three parameters, two of which are optional. The first parameter is the input string, with the second being a format string, and third being a NLS locale string.

The output of TO_NUMBER() is a NUMBER datatype, and Oracle has a good number of NUMBER datatypes including FLOAT, DEC, INTEGER, INT, REAL, etc.

My question is -- how does TO_NUMBER() determine which specific numeric datatype to return? Is it determined by the first optional parameter, the format string?

Comment: No...  There is only one `NUMBER` data type. It is a **numeric** data type, analogous to `FLOAT`, `INTEGER` etc. Some of those are actually defined as **sub-types** of `NUMBER`, but that is irrelevant for your question. `TO_NUMBER()` always returns `NUMBER`, not `FLOAT`, not `INT`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As @mathguy has pointed out, TO_NUMBER always returns a NUMBER.  You can check this out yourself with the DUMP function. It will return the datatype and the internal representation of the data, eg

```
SQL> select dump(to_number('1')) from dual;

DUMP(TO_NUMBER('1'
------------------
Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2

SQL> select dump(to_number('1.123')) from dual;

DUMP(TO_NUMBER('1.123'))
------------------------
Typ=2 Len=4: 193,2,13,31
```

Even a float when passed to TO_NUMBER will become a NUMBER

```
SQL> select dump(to_number(1.0e+3f)) from dual;

DUMP(TO_NUMBER(1.0E
-------------------
Typ=2 Len=2: 194,11
```